# Run PowerShell command from command prompt (no ps1 script)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm looking for a way to run just a couple PowerShell commands from the command prompt. I don't want to create a script for this since it's just a couple commands I need to run and since I don't really know how to script with PowerShell.

Here is the command I'm trying to use to start with:

```
Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Directory <folderpath> -Recurse -FileType <type>
```

I don't really want to create a script for this as it would be much easier if I can just run one or two commands from a batch file with the rest of the stuff.

EDIT:
Here is what I've tried so far.

1)

```
powershell -Command "Get-AppLockerFileInformation....."
Error: The term 'Get-AppLockerFileInformation is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....
```

2)

```
powershell -Command {Get-AppLockerFileInformation.....}
```

No error with this way but I don't get anything back. If I use the `Set-AppLockerPolicy...` nothing happens.

3)

```
powershell -Command "{Get-AppLockerFileInformation.....}"
Error: The term 'Get-AppLockerFileInformation is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....
```

4)

```
powershell -Command "& {Get-AppLockerFileInformation.....}"
Error: The term 'Get-AppLockerFileInformation is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....
```

5)

```
powershell "& {Get-AppLockerFileInformation.....}"
Error: The term 'Get-AppLockerFileInformation is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....
```

6)

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command {Get-AppLockerFileInformation....}
```

No error but nothing happens.

7)

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-AppLockerFileInformation...."
```

No error but nothing happens.

Comment: On one hand you say "I don't really want to create a script" and on the other hand you say "if I can just run one or two commands from a batch file".  So:  which is it???

Comment: I should clarify, I don't want to create a powershell script.

Comment: And `Get-AppLockerFileInformation` works fine for you when running from a new fresh and clean powershell prompt? What OS? (tested Get-App.. in Win7 and there is no such cmdlet in that case so get the same error message)

Comment: I first use the `Import-Module AppLocker` command to load the library. I'm using Windows Embedded 7. Maybe I need to combine the 2 calls, import the library then run the command...??

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/a/19111810](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19111810) may be relevant for you.  
It is about how to combine .cmd and .ps1 into 1 file (.cmd).

Comment: @homay2 Thx for the reference, looks good. I will definitely have to look at that more since I'm still a bit new with PowerShell.

Comment: Not sure why my answer was deleted... I found the solution and posted it as these other answers did NOT solve my problem. For ref, try: `powershell -command "& {&'some-command' someParam}"` or for multiple commands try: `powershell -command "& {&'some-command' someParam}"; "& {&'some-command' -SpecificArg someParam}"`. This link helped out: http://forloveofsoftware.blogspot.ca/2009/04/calling-powershell-script-in-path-with.html

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is the **only answer** that managed to work for my problem, got it figured out with the help of [this](http://forloveofsoftware.blogspot.ca/2009/04/calling-powershell-script-in-path-with.html) webpage (nice reference).

```
powershell -command "& {&'some-command' someParam}"
```

Also, here is a neat way to do multiple commands:

```
powershell -command "& {&'some-command' someParam}"; "& {&'some-command' -SpecificArg someParam}"
```

For example, this is how I ran my 2 commands:

```
powershell -command "& {&'Import-Module' AppLocker}"; "& {&'Set-AppLockerPolicy' -XmlPolicy myXmlFilePath.xml}"
```

Comment: Here's another useful trick, you can run a ps1 script from the command prompt and pass in args like so: `powershell.exe -File "C:\myfile.ps1" arg1 arg2 arg3` or `powershell.exe -File "C:\myfile.ps1" -Some-Command arg1 -Another-Command arg2`

Comment: The command `powershell -command "& {&'Import-Module' AppLocker}"; "& {&'Set-AppLockerPolicy' -XmlPolicy myXmlFilePath.xml}"` runs these 2 PS commands in separate PS sessions, i.e. it is not applicable If you need to share some variable between 2 commands. The solution is as follows: `powershell -command "& {$someVar = 'test'; &'Write-Host' $someVar}"`

Comment: @Maciej I don't think it runs in different PS sessions otherwise the second part of this specific command would fail since I need that module loaded from the first part of the command. I disagree. But, there may some value in sharing variables if needed, as you mention.

Comment: Great answer. Small extension: I needed to start the powershell command in a new window from the command prompt and found that the following worked:
`start powershell -Command "& cd C:\somedir; npm start"`

Comment: It doesn't work for me : using Windows 11 in 2023. I get error "The term [...] is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file etc...

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães I haven't tried it on Windows 11, but do you need to use the `Import-Module` command as part of your command string?

Answer (score 13):

Run it on a single command line like so:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile 
  -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Directory <folderpath> 
  -Recurse -FileType <type>"
```

Comment: As soon as I get a chance I will try this out. There seems to be a lot of flags in there though, would it be the same if I want to use Set-AppLockerPolicy and New-AppLockerPolicy?

Comment: This didn't work, not to mention the <code>-WindowStyle</code> flag closes my command prompt... Also, I don't need the <code>ExecutionPolicy</code> flag since I'm using the command line directly.

Comment: Yes, some of the options are probably unnecessary.  Just tweak depending on what you need.  More info here: http://zduck.com/2012/powershell-batch-files-exit-codes/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `powershell -Command "Get-AppLockerFileInformation....."`

Take a look at `powershell /?`

Comment: That's what I've been trying but I don't seem to be getting the syntax quite right or something. When I run the command directly from the powershell it works fine though...

Comment: Ok, Do you get any error or something else? Please edit your question and provide more information. What have you tried and what does not work etc.

Comment: This syntax worked for me.  One caveat I saw is it doesn't work with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This works from my Windows 10's cmd.exe prompt

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Import-Module C:\Users\william\ps1\TravelBook; Get-TravelBook Hawaii"
```

This example shows

1. how to chain multiple commands
2. how to import module with module path
3. how to run a function defined in the module
4. No need for those fancy "&".

Comment: Yes, to run scripts you need to change your local execution policy....