# Visual Studio prebuild powershell script exiting with code 9009 and failing to build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, pre-build-event

In my project I have set pre-build event that updates content of *.cs and *.xaml files (which are included in project being built).

I use `Set-Content` Powershell command for it.

When I test it in Powershell console everything is working perfectly.

But when I paste as in pre-build event it generates error with code 9009 and prevents VS from successfully building my project.

I have set build output verbosity to `Diagnostic`, but there's no more information on it.

What could be the problem?

My current guess is that VS locks files for building, thus Powershell commands can't modify them.

Comment: Error 9009 can mean `'XXX' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, though `Set-Content` sound an unlikely candidate for that.  As a test, can you get `Set-Content` to write to another, unrelated, file (from VS) just to be sure the script as a whole is working?

Comment: @boxdog As I said, I tested it in Powershell console, everything is working fine there.

Comment: Yes, but did you test via VS just to be sure it is an issue with the particular files you're targetting?

Comment: @boxdog Tested it with another file, same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use Set-Content Powershell command for it. What could be the problem?

**The cause of the issue:**

1.VS will call something like `cmd.exe` to execute the command you type in `Build Events`.

That means you're trying to run `Set-content` command in `cmd.exe`.

2.Like **boxdog** said, `code9009` in VS do indicate `the command is not recognized`.

More specifically, the `Set-content` is PowerShell command, not command recognized by **`cmd.exe`**.(See #1, VS calls cmd.exe to run the command).

So the issue occurs: `Type a PowerShell command in build events => VS calls cmd.exe to execute it => cmd.exe can't recognize a PS command. and throw error=> VS output log displays error code9009.`

**Suggestions:**

You can't **directly** type `Set-content` in build events to run(equipment to run `Set-content` directly in CMD and it will cause error).

Instead we can call `powershell` to run PS script or PS command in `cmd.exe`, you can find many related topics about how to run PS script from CMD online. See [run PS command in cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd), [run PS from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454653/run-powershell-command-from-command-prompt-no-ps1-script), [How to run PS in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436405/how-to-run-powershell-in-cmd). But it's more like another issue, so I don't talk too much here:)

In summary: You can choose to create a new PS script and move your `Set-content` command into it, and type command like `powershell -file path\xx.ps1` or simple `powershell - command` in build events. Then the `Error9009` would go away. (I believe the Error9009 would go away, but I've seen too many issues about other Error Codes, most of them are related to path issues, so take care about the Path defined in your script.)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks :)