# VS2019 - msbuild is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am using VS2019 community and I've set pre-build event:

```
msbuild "$(ProjectPath)" /t:Clean
```

I am getting error:

```
  'MSBuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file
```

How is this possible? Isn't this command supposed to be build into visual studio?

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319274/how-do-i-run-msbuild-from-the-command-line-using-windows-sdk-7-1) and tried to set path environment, but it doesn't help.

Does anybody else has the same problem with this command in VS2019?

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? You can try my answer to check if it helps to resolve that issue. It does work in my machine :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With latest update to VS2019 - version 16.3.4 - the error is no longer there.

Answer (score 9):

Steps that work in my machine:

1. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119480/visual-studio-prebuild-powershell-script-exiting-with-code-9009-and-failing-to-b/58127448#58127448), first we need to make sure `MSBuild` can be recognized by `cmd.exe`.
2. If the command can be recognized by `cmd.exe` but not build-event from VS, restart the PC can help resolve this issue.

   (Something strange is that for my VS still can't recognize it until a restart of the computer)
3. For VS2019, the correct msbuild path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

And here's another workaround:

Apart from adding the path of `msbuild.exe` into `Environment Path` and call it in `pre-build` event, you can also consider using [MSBuild Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2019).

Add script below into `xx.csproj`:(work for .net framework...)

```
  <Target Name="MyCleanBeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectPath)" Targets="clean"/>
    <!--<Message Text="Custom Clean" Importance="high"/>-->
  </Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, you can consider adding it as answer to share the useful info. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 3):

Using "dotnet" instead of "msbuild" could work if you got that installed.

So, in my case, instead of running "msbuild /t:restore" I figured I can use "dotnet build" and have the same result.

Here's the documentation in case you want to see more equivalent commands.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows computer:

1. Search for Environment Variables
2. Edit Path
3. New
4. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin