# Including PSGallery nuget dependency in Visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, nuget-package

**Problem**

How to share postbuild Powershell Script in multiple solution so that each solution can invoke the script in post build event?

**Solution Approach**

- Created a local [PSGallary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories?view=powershell-6)
- Pushed my script into the gallery
- In the VS, added the new PSGallary as a nuget Source
- Pulled the postbuild script as the nuget package in the solution

Now i am stuck. The script is saved outside the solution in a nuget folder like this.
[image]

I don't want to hardcode the path of the script since, the versions changes and so does the path. How can i get the path of the actual nuget package content in post build event without hard coding it? is there other better approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's better approach for you, here're two directions which may help:

1.**Nuget way:** Include your powershell script as [content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) when creating the nuget package, then when you build the project, the script will be copied to output path automatically. So you can specify the post-build event with macro `$(OutputPath)`. Anyone interested in it can check [blog here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/).

For your `.net core` project which uses PackageReference, use the [ContentFiles element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files). There's many topics about how to create the package with content files using `ContentFiles` element online, so I won't talk details here, but if you want to choose this way and meet some issues, let me know that :)

2.**MSBuild way**: Using something like [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) to customize your build. Since your original problem is to `share postbuild Powershell Script in multiple solution`, let's place the script `test.ps1` in path `C:\PostBuildScript\`, let's create a .txt file with content below, and then rename it to `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ScriptPath>C:\xxx\xxx\</ScriptPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now if we place this file in Solution-A's directory, all projects in A solution can recognize `$(ScriptPath)`, so we can use parameter like `$(ScriptPath)test.ps1` in build event. If you meet code9009 when calling PS script in build event, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119480/visual-studio-prebuild-powershell-script-exiting-with-code-9009-and-failing-to-b/58127448#58127448).

And if those solutions are under folder `TestFolder`, place the `Directory.Build.props` file in that folder, it will work for all solutions in that folder. Also, there's many directions to customize your post-build events, it depends on your needs...

Comment: I will try and let u know.. Thanks

Comment: I did the nuget way following https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/. It works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to know it helps. Answer updated with the blog link you share :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use the [Nuget CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-install) with the `OutputDirectory` parameter to install the package in the project directory. Afterwards you can use the `$(ProjectDir)` macro in your post build event.

Comment: Its an option. I tried it. It looks like I cannot manage/update package through VS > Manage Nuget Packages> update or delete. Also if i update the package using the command the , it will change the path of the script ..